# No output files from mahout

Tags: hadoop, mahout, syncfusion, mahout-recommender

I am running a mahout recommenderJob on hadoop in syncfusion. I get the following. But no output... it seems to run indefinitely

[image]

[image]

Does anyone have an idea why I am not getting an `output.txt` from this? Why does this seem to run indefinitely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this could be due to the insufficient disk space in your machine and in this case, I'd suggest you to clean up your disk space and try this again from your end.

In alternate, I'd also suggest you to use the **Syncfusion Cluster Manager** - using which you can form a cluster with multiple nodes/machines, so that there will be suffifient memory available to execute your job.

-Ramkumar

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. It was indeed a disk space issue. I freed up some memory and then I had to leave safe mode, now everything is running fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the same map reduce job which you're trying to execute using Syncfusion BigData Studio and it worked for me.

Please find the input details which I've used from the following,

**Command:**

```
hadoop jar E:\mahout-examples-0.12.2-job.jar org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob -s SIMILARITY_COOCCURRENCE --input=/Input.txt --output=output
```

**Sample input (Input.txt):**

For input data, I've used the data available in Apache - Mahout site (refer below link) and saved the same in a text file.

http://mahout.apache.org/users/recommender/userbased-5-minutes.html

[image]

I've also seen a misspelled word **"COOCCURRENCE"** used in your command. Please correct this, or else you could face "Class Not Found Exception".

**Output:**

Please find the generated output from below.

[image]

-Ramkumar :)